# Build HTML report for AxeCore with Java

Tags: java, html, report, accessibility, axe

I'm using axe core library for accessibility testing, and the current report doesn't fit my needs. Results are generated under json and txt formats.
Looks like for javascript, there is a way to convert data into a nice HTML report, but I'm looking after a solution also for Java.
Does anyone have any solution for this?

Axe core library:
https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core